# Why does Google Now never think that I will arrive on time?

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, google-now

I have a Nexus 5 running Android 5.0.1.

Whenever a notification appears in Google Now about an upcoming event, it always tells me "The transportation mode you selected will not let you arrive on time", no matter how close the event is, and how long in the future the event is.

For example, I had the following notification today:

[image: GoogleNow notification]

Something doesn't add up:

- You can see from the clock at the top that it was 9:27.
- The event was starting at 10:30, not that far away.
- It tells me to leave at 10:23 (seems reasonable, given the distance)
- But then it tells me I won't arrive at time

What's going on here?

By the way, I have Location Services turned on.

Comment: Maybe google now knows you are always late to events... kidding. That is interesting. Maybe even though you have location services on, it is unable to get an accurate location.

Comment: It wants you to leave 7 minutes before the party. It states that it takes 8 minutes to get there. Therefore you won't arrive on time. Just me, or is this logical?

Comment: @saloalv - but why not suggest leaving 1 minute earlier? Pretty much every time i have an event, it says the same thing.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat I do not know why it doesn't suggest leaving earlier, I was just stating the fact that if you leave as late as it wants, you'll be late, which is the reason behind the message shown in the app

Comment: @saloalv - fair enough. Unless the extra 1 minute is from the "light traffic" which is always added on to the minimum time.

Comment: I have the same phone and I'm getting the same message. I don't think it has to do with the traffic, or if it does it isn't calculated, because I have over an hour drive and it is always off by 1 minute. Did you ever find a reason or a fix?

Comment: I can hide the "error" by clicking the down arrow and selecting the car as transportation mode.

Comment: No fix yet @mikeyprog

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat Ok, next time you get it try what I wrote above. It doesn't answer the why, but it has hidden the error for me.

Comment: Does it hide it permanently @mikeyprog, or just the one time?

Comment: It appears so, it lasted through a reboot, but after I added a test event I accidentally swiped away the card, so I'll have to wait.

Comment: It turns out it does not hide it permanently. It only works for that specific event.